# Available Approvers Based on List Item Column Value

Tags: workflow

Is it possible (without custom forms) to create an approval workflow that filters the list of available approvers based on some value in a list item ?

To be a bit more clear.. if the list item had a choice field called "Division" and there was another list that associated users to divisions, when initiating approval is it possible to limit the selection of approvers to users associated with the selected division ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you tied to the OOTB approval workflows?  If not, then that can easily be created via SharePoint Designer.

Comment: I'm not tied to OOTB, just trying to minimize re-inventing the wheel through custom code.  Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Here is a good example, http://www.gandhipritesh.com/2009/07/create-custom-approval-workflow-using.html.  In your case, you're going to want to have some logic that looks up to your list of people to find who the appropriate person is for the selected division value and assign the task to that person.

Comment: Thanks - it's not quite what I am after.  Ideally what I'm looking for is a way to present a filtered list of approvers, which the submitter can then select from

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  You might be able to use the cascading drop down function from spservices.codeplex.com to present that to users.  I misintreprted the desired outcome.